# Anaconda runs Java 11, but I need to run PySpark on Java 8

Tags: java, python-3.x, macos, pyspark, anaconda

I am trying to run PySpark with Anaconda Jupyter on Mac.
When I installed Apache-Spark and PySpark, I was getting some errors during the execution.

I read some recommendations on stack overflow regarding this issue, that I should use Java8 instead of later versions.
I checked Java versions on Mac OS, and I found twoL java 11.0.1 and Java 8

I removed Java 11 from OS.
but when I tried to the code again, I got the same error.
I checked Java version on Anaconda, from java console on Anaconda, and I found it's java 11.0.1

How can I change the version of Java that Anaconda using?
Any other suggestion or verified approach to install and use PySpark with Jupyter on Mac OS, is really appreciated.

Thanks